# Cpu Usage simple bash "integer expected error "

Tags: bash, cpu

It seems everything right but not work in line 10 get error integer expression expected

```
#!/bin/bash

default="50.0%"
# Continuously
while true; do

    state=$(top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix="$prefix" '{ split($1, vs, ","); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%s%.1f%%\n", prefix, 100 - v }')
        
    # If it changed
    if [ "$state" -ge "$default" ] ; then

        # Alarm 
        echo "Cpu Usage High"        
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: You have % in the default variable?

Comment: Neither `state` nor `default` are integers.

Comment: BTW, it's very roundabout to get these numbers from `top` instead of just getting them straight out of `/proc` (which is where `top` itself gets them from, if you're on Linux).